# Drag and Drop Images browse upload issue in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, drag-and-drop, image-upload

**JSP Form** :

```
    <s:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploaddocumentfile" id="uploaddocumentfile" namespace="/documents" >
        <s:file name="upload" id="holder"></s:file>
   /s:form>
```

**jQuery**:

```
function readfiles(files) {
    console.log(files);
    var a=files[0].name;  // name of file 
    $("#uploaddocumentfile").submit(); // problem :how to pass value in action class of type File upload  getter setter
}
var holder = document.getElementById('holder');
holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
     this.className = '';
    // console.log(e.dataTransfer.files[0].path);
     e.preventDefault();
     readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
    }
```

**Action class**:
public class UploadFilesAction extends ... {

```
private File upload;

public File getUpload() {
    return upload;
}
public void setUpload(File upload) {
    this.upload = upload;
}
}
```

problem : in browse file upload we can get form file value in action class automatically by File upload getter setter  but drag drop how can we get file values

Comment: jsp form <s:form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploaddocumentfile" id="uploaddocumentfile" namespace="/documents" >
 <s:file name="upload" id="holder"></s:file>
          </s:form>

Comment: file upload example in struts : https://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-file-upload-example      same type need to drag and drop file uploads

Comment: The drag and drop on that example is working fine.. https://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-file-upload-example

Comment: this is not drag and drop , java point example is browse image file examle .. drag drop means  from computer drag a file and drop in webpage specific area ..http://html5demos.com/dnd-upload

Comment: Try drag files to choose file button it can be upload.If you want a div to act like a drag and drop for file you need to use jquery plugins like http://www.dropzonejs.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin to achieve drag and drop files

**JSP**

```
<div id="template_dropzone"></div>
```

**Script**

```
var profilePic = null;
var dropZone = $('#template_dropzone').dropzone({
                 url: "#",
                 maxFiles: 1,
                 addRemoveLinks: true,
                 init: function() {
                    this.on("addedfile", function(file) {
                     // trigger when a file is added
                 });
                     this.on("complete", function(file) {
                       // trigger when the uploading of a file is completed
                        profilePic = file;
                  });
                     this.on("removedfile", function(file) {
                         var noOfFiles =  this.files.length; // can check No. of files
                  });
               });
    $('#uploadFile').on('click',function(event){
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append('upload',profilePic);
       $.ajax({
           url: 'uploadProfilePic',
           method: 'POST',
           data: data,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(result) {}
        });
    });
```

In Action class you can retrieve file name or content type by simply creating a String variable with getters and setters like below:-

```
    private File upload;
    private String uploadFileName;
    private String uploadContentType;

    public File getUpload() {
        return upload;
    }

    public void setUpload(File upload) {
        this.upload = upload;
    }

    public String getUploadFileName() {
        return uploadFileName;
    }

    public void setUploadFileName(String uploadFileName) {
        this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
    }

    public String getUploadFileContentType() {
        return uploadFileContentType;
    }

    public void setUploadFileContentType(String uploadFileContentType) {
        this.uploadFileContentType = uploadFileContentType;
    }
```

Comment: i do not want to use any plugin..  can i pass profilePic value as a value in my code and insted of calling onclick listner can call directly in read file..
function readfiles(files) {
    console.log(files);

    var a=files[0].name;  // name of file 
 var data = new FormData();
      data.append('upload',a);
       $.ajax({
           url: 'uploadProfilePic',
           method: 'POST',
           data: data,
           cache: false,
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,
           success: function(result) {}
        });
......

Comment: if using dropzone js then jsp  file will
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
  <div class="template_dropzone">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
 <input type ="submit"   name="uploadFile"    id="uploadFile"     />
  </div>
</form>

Comment: Yes you can. make sure `a` is file not file name `var a=files[0];'

Comment: The request is send via ajax not form submit.

Comment: can you give me exact jsp file

Comment: If you want to upload file the moment it is dropped into the div.Use ajax inside `this.on("complete", function(file) {}` else you can upload it with a button click,like in the example.No need to create form in html.Add form action to ajax url parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143774/discussion-between-prince-radhakrishnan-and-kaml).

Comment: It is worth noting that, to upload multiple files with Struts2 and dropzone.js, a custom hack is needed. Luckily, [I've documented it here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26080212/1654265) ;)